# Ubuntu 22.04 not booting on Dell XPS 13 9320 after fresh install (Dual boot Windows 11)

Tags: dual-boot, 22.04, dell, encryption

I recently bought a Dell XPS 13 9320 with Windows 11 pre-installed with the intention to install Ubuntu alongside on dual boot, with encryption.

I followed these instructions: https://www.mikekasberg.com/blog/2020/04/08/dual-boot-ubuntu-and-windows-with-encryption.html

After the install of Ubuntu, I get to the startup menu to choose between Ubuntu and Windows 11. Windows boots correctly. Ubuntu does not boot. I get this message after the screen with the ubuntu logo:

```
[ 0.588520] pci 0000:00:07.0: DPC: RP PIO log size 0 is invalid
[ 0.589203] pci 0000:00:07.2: DPC: RP PIO log size 0 is invalid

BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-7ubuntu3) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for list of built-in commands. 

(initramfs)
```

What does it mean and how to solve this issue?

Bios settings (UEFI):

- Secured boot : on
- TPM 2.0 Security : on
- Absolute: enabled
- Raid ON-mode for SSD-conf.

Disk Management snapshop:

[image: Disk Management snapshop]

Comment: Most systems only work with one ESP - efi system partition per device. You show two? My Dell with 11th Gen Intel just worked with Kubuntu 22.04. I actually forgot to change settings normally suggested for Dell and most other systems. But I do not use  encryption. Aflter a Dell total recovery erased my Kubuntu install, I now use an external SSD which  seems just as fast as internal drive. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report) Use updated ppa version. 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair Do not think boot issue, report may help.